# Class not found when running program from command line

Tags: java, classpath

Here is the structure of my project:

```
MyProject
-lib
   -mp3agic-0.9.0.jar

-src
   -com.company
      -Main.java
```

Inside Main, I import the content of mp3agic:

import com.mpatric.mp3agic.*;

From MyProject, I compile the class using:

javac -cp "lib/*" src/com/company/Main.java

From MyProject/src, I try to run the program with:

java -cp . com/company/Main

and I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mpatric/mp3agic/InvalidDataException

Apparently, the jdk can not find the dependencies from the lib folder when running the class, albeit this problem doesn't occur when compiling.
I guess there's a problem with the syntax of the command, but I just can't find it.

Can you please help me?

EDIT: I solved the problem, moving the lib folder under src and then running:

C:\MyProject\src>javac -cp "lib/*" com/company/Main.java

C:\MyProject\src>java -cp .;"lib/*" com/company/Main

Now, the code compiles and executes without any issue.

HOWEVER, if I leave lib under the project root, this is what happens:

C:\MyProject>javac -cp "lib/*" src/com/company/Main.java

C:\MyProject>java -cp .;"lib/*" src/com/company/Main

Error: Could not find or load main class src.com.company.Main

WHY?

Comment: `Apparently, the jdk can not find the dependencies from the lib folder when running the class, albeit this problem doesn't occur when compiling.` Because you're adding `lib/*` to the classpath when compiling but not when running.

Comment: You need *both* the library *and* your code on the classpath. Entries on the classpath are separated by ";" on Windows and by ":" on everything else. So try `-cp .;lib/*`

Comment: You explicitly tell Javac about your lib folder. You must do the same with the java command

Comment: I tried with java -cp .;lib/* com/company/main, and now I get Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.main

Comment: @AlexReds: do you have a class named `com.company.main`? Hint: case matters.

Comment: @Joachim: yes, it's like in the project structure from above.

Comment: @AlexReds: no, you don't. Again: classes are case sensitive.

Comment: @Joachim: fair point, but I don't think this was a problem, please have a look at the comment update.

Comment: @AlexReds: you also don't have a class in the package `src.com.company`. Despite your using `/` to separate the class name instead of `.`, the `java` command needs the *class name* of the class to execute, not the *path to the .class file*. In short: your `-cp` must point to the directory that contains the `com` directory (which contains `company` which contains `Main.class`). And the last argument must be the fully-qualified *name* of the class you need to run: `com.company.Main`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use maven or gradle or you'll have to say which console are your using, and which operating system -if you don't know what a console is, you'll first have to google for that before messing with `javac` directly- But if you insist:

for Linux, OSX, any UNIX-like:

`javac -cp ".:lib/mp3agic-0.9.0.jar" src/com/company/Main.java`

for Windows:

`javac -cp ".;lib/mp3agic-0.9.0.jar" src/com/company/Main.java`

To run under windows:

`java -cp .;lib\mp4agic-0.9.0.jar com.company.Main`

You may need to use slash (/) instead of backslash depending of which console you're using. Or just try "/" or "\" and see what works for you.

If you still get class not found exception, then the issue is not related with classpath or `java` command but on your code (hard to say, without seeing the code).

Comment: I'm on Windows and I use the Intellij terminal. As mentioned in my post, I can compile without any problem but i get a NoClassDefFoundError when I run it.

Comment: Then do java -cp .;lib\your-jar-dependency.jar com.company.Main (just added to the answer also)

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mpatric.mp3agic.InvalidDataException

Answer (score 0):

java.exe -classpath {path} Main

I think you have to add classpath also and when run the program(not only compile)